# HTML table to Loop Through each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML table which have a input field by default it is `0` initially, what I am doing is I am saving all the `Items` which have a value greater than 0, so it is working fine, but at `UI` end what i want to do is when user initially loads the page it shows up HTML table with one column having input field and values as `0`, so if user clicks on save without entering any value in input field then I am trying to prompt an alert `quantity field value should be greater then 0`, but when I am doing this it is only checking for 1st row

**Code**

```js
var tableDataDraft = [


  {
    "Code": "1248",
    "Item Name": "Tandoori Roti",
    "Selling Price": "45.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1249",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1250",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1251",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Garlic",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1252",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1253",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1254",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Amritsari",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1255",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Punjabi",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1256",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Jaipuar",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1257",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Aloo",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1258",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Methi",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1259",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Pudina",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1260",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Lacha",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },

  {
    "Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Selling Price": "134.8700",
    "Qty": "0"
  }
]

var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var categoryName = tableDataDraft[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Outlet Id'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Outlet_Id');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.classList.add("dheeraj")
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("max", "999");
        // quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)

$("#save").click(function() {
  var emptyQuantity = $(".dataReset").val(); //on click of save want to check quantity field should be greater then zero 
  if (emptyQuantity === '0') {
    alert("Quantity field Value  Should be greater then 0");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
    <i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save
   </button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="indentTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

  </table>
</div>
```

So what I want to achieve  is

- If any Quantity field has value greater then 0 then i can allow user to save data,but if all the input fields have value 0 in each row then trying to prompt message
- Currently what it is doing it only checks 1st row if it has value greater then zero then it saves data otherwise prompt mesage
- So in case when user let 1st row data be zero and other data He/She entered any thing then it is checking only  First Row

i have commented the Save button code in my snippet

Any kind of help or approach will be appreciated,Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers check if each item has a quantity of more than 0. Your function to check if the user has selected at least one item to buy should look like this:

```js
var tableDataDraft = [


    {
      "Code": "1248",
      "Item Name": "Tandoori Roti",
      "Selling Price": "45.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1249",
      "Item Name": "Naan-Plain",
      "Selling Price": "50.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1250",
      "Item Name": "Naan-Butter",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1251",
      "Item Name": "Naan-Garlic",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1252",
      "Item Name": "Kulcha-Plain",
      "Selling Price": "50.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1253",
      "Item Name": "Kulcha-Butter",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1254",
      "Item Name": "Kulcha-Amritsari",
      "Selling Price": "65.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1255",
      "Item Name": "Kulcha-Punjabi",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1256",
      "Item Name": "Kulcha-Jaipuar",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1257",
      "Item Name": "Paratha-Aloo",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1258",
      "Item Name": "Paratha-Methi",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1259",
      "Item Name": "Paratha-Pudina",
      "Selling Price": "60.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
    {
      "Code": "1260",
      "Item Name": "Paratha-Lacha",
      "Selling Price": "55.0000",
      "Qty": "0"
    },
  
    {
      "Code": "603",
      "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
      "Selling Price": "134.8700",
      "Qty": "0"
    }
  ]
  
  var itemsQuantiry1 = [];
  
  function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
    var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
    var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
    var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
    col = col.concat(num);
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
      var th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = col[i];
      tr.appendChild(th);
      tr.classList.add("text-center");
      tr.classList.add("head")
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
      tr = table.insertRow(-1);
      tr.classList.add("item-row");
      for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        var categoryName = tableDataDraft[i]["Category Name"];
        tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
        let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.style.display = "none";
        var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
        if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableDataDraft[i]['Outlet Id'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
          hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Outlet_Id');
          hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
          tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
        if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
          tabCell.classList.add("dheeraj")
          var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
          quantityField.style.border = "none";
          quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
          quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
          quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
  
          if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
            quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
          } else {
            quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
          }
          quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
          quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
          quantityField.setAttribute("min", "0");
          quantityField.setAttribute("max", "999");
          // quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
          quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
          quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
          quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
          tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
        }
  
        if (j > 1)
          tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
      }
    }
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
    table.classList.add("table");
    table.classList.add("table-striped");
    table.classList.add("table-bordered");
    table.classList.add("table-hover");
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    addTableDraft(tableDataDraft);
    });

function Save() {
    count = 0;
    var qtys = document.getElementsByName("Quantity_field");

    for (i=0; i < qtys.length; i++) {
        if(qtys[i].value !== "0") {
            // There is atleast one item that the user has changed the qty for
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        alert("Thanks for buying something");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please buy something");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="site.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton" onclick="Save();">
    <i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save
</button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="indentTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

  </table>
</div>
```

This checks to see if atleast one of the items has a quantity of 1 or more.

Comment: hey can you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846400/appended-new-row-is-not-behaving-like-previous-one-row

Answer (score 1):

You can try keeping it in a loop, so that it checks for each such row having a value `1` also once it is found we need to break the `each` loop after your `alert`.

```js
var tableDataDraft = [


  {
    "Code": "1248",
    "Item Name": "Tandoori Roti",
    "Selling Price": "45.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1249",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1250",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1251",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Garlic",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1252",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1253",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1254",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Amritsari",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1255",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Punjabi",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1256",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Jaipuar",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1257",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Aloo",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1258",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Methi",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1259",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Pudina",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1260",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Lacha",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },

  {
    "Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Selling Price": "134.8700",
    "Qty": "0"
  }
]

var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var categoryName = tableDataDraft[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Outlet Id'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Outlet_Id');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.classList.add("dheeraj")
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("max", "999");
        // quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)

$("#save").click(function() {
  $(".dataReset").each(function(){
  var emptyQuantity = $(this).val(); //on click of save want to check quantity field should be greater then zero 
  if (emptyQuantity === '0') {
    alert("Quantity field Value  Should be greater then 0");
    return false;
  }
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
    <i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save
   </button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="indentTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Same issue is there ,i am letting 1st row as 0 then entering any number in second or any row then it should not prompt any alert

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
                <i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save
            </button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="indentTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tableDataDraft = [


  {
    "Code": "1248",
    "Item Name": "Tandoori Roti",
    "Selling Price": "45.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1249",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1250",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1251",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Garlic",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1252",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1253",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1254",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Amritsari",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1255",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Punjabi",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1256",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Jaipuar",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1257",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Aloo",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1258",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Methi",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1259",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Pudina",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1260",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Lacha",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },

  {
    "Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Selling Price": "134.8700",
    "Qty": "0"
  }
]

var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var categoryName = tableDataDraft[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Outlet Id'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Outlet_Id');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.classList.add("dheeraj")
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("max", "999");
        //  quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)
checkValidation=function(){
var valid=true;
    $(".dataReset").each(function(){
    if($(this).val().trim()!=""){
        if(parseInt($(this).val())==0){
        valid=false;
        return;
      }
    }
  });
  // console.log(valid)
  return valid;
}
$("#save").click(function() {
  // var emptyQuantity = $(".dataReset").val(); //on click of save want to check quantity field should be greater then zero 
  if (!checkValidation()) {
    alert("Quantity field Value  Should be greater then 0");
  }else{
    alert("All is set")
  }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added line of codes at the bottom of your jquery. I used `.each()` function of every 4th `<td>` of the table.

```js
var tableDataDraft = [


  {
    "Code": "1248",
    "Item Name": "Tandoori Roti",
    "Selling Price": "45.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1249",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1250",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1251",
    "Item Name": "Naan-Garlic",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1252",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Plain",
    "Selling Price": "50.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1253",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Butter",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1254",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Amritsari",
    "Selling Price": "65.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1255",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Punjabi",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1256",
    "Item Name": "Kulcha-Jaipuar",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1257",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Aloo",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1258",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Methi",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1259",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Pudina",
    "Selling Price": "60.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },
  {
    "Code": "1260",
    "Item Name": "Paratha-Lacha",
    "Selling Price": "55.0000",
    "Qty": "0"
  },

  {
    "Code": "603",
    "Item Name": "AMUL FRESH CREAM",
    "Selling Price": "134.8700",
    "Qty": "0"
  }
]

var itemsQuantiry1 = [];

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      var categoryName = tableDataDraft[i]["Category Name"];
      tr.dataset.category = categoryName;
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Selling Price'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Selling_Price');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Outlet Id'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Outlet_Id');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Qty'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.classList.add("dheeraj")
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");

        if (itemsQuantiry1[i]) {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry1[i]);
        } else {
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("min", "0");
        quantityField.setAttribute("max", "999");
        // quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)
        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("indentTable");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
}
addTableDraft(tableDataDraft)

$("#save").click(function(event) {
  var emptyQuantity = $(".dataReset").val(); //on click of save want to check quantity field should be greater then zero 
  var data = [];
  $("tr td:nth-child(4)").each(function() {
      data.push($(this).find("input").val());
    });
  
  if(data.indexOf("0") > -1){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Quantity field Value  Should be greater then 0");
  }
  else{
    alert("Submitted");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
    <i class="fas fa-save"></i>&nbsp;Save
   </button>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="indentTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover ">

  </table>
</div>
```